# Replace missing values with column mean

Tags: r, missing-data, imputation

I am not sure how to loop over each column to replace the NA values with the column mean. When I am trying to replace for one column using the following, it works well.

```
Column1[is.na(Column1)] <- round(mean(Column1, na.rm = TRUE))
```

The code for looping over columns is not working:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(data)){
    data[i][is.na(data[i])] <- round(mean(data[i], na.rm = TRUE))
}
```

the values are not replaced. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Replacing missing values with the mean of a column is statistical malpractice.

Comment: @BondedDust The reason I did so was because if I ignored those NA values my data-set shrink to a very small number. Can you suggest what is the best way to handle such problems. If you could provide some link to a blog it would be great

Comment: If you want to replace with something as a quick hack, you could try replacing the NA's like `mean(x) +rnorm(length(missing(x)))*sd(x)`. That will not take account of correlations between the missings (or the correlations of the measured), but at least it won't seriously inflate the significance of the results. Better would be to get experience with the packages that handle imputation of missing values. There are quite a few subtleties underlying the problem.

Comment: @42-  I realize this comment's a couple years old.  However, was the code literally meant `mean(x)+rnorm(length(missing(x)))*sd(x)`?  When I run it, I get `Error in missing(x) : invalid use of 'missing'`.  I expect the intention was to take the mean of the available values for x, then add rnorm(length of NAs)*sd(available values for x).  Correct?  I loved the malpractice line :-).  I'm personally looking for a quick hack because I'm working with the '98 KDD cup dataset that has 120+ attributes with NAs.  I'd like to drop most of them, and the instructions are to exclude only >= .995 NA . . .

Comment: By the way, this is what I inferred the intended code was:  `mean(x, na.rm = T)+rnorm(sum(is.na(x)))*sd(x, na.rm = T)`

Comment: Was meant more as pseudo-code. Would need proper indexing but perhaps `rnorm( n=sum(is.na(x)) , mean=mean(x),  sd=sd(x) )` would be closer to working code.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

A relatively simple modification of your code should solve the issue:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(data)){
  data[is.na(data[,i]), i] <- mean(data[,i], na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

Answer (score 64):

If `DF` is your data frame of numeric columns:

```
library(zoo)
na.aggregate(DF)
```

ADDED:

Using only the base of R define a function which does it for one column and then lapply to every column:

```
NA2mean <- function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))
replace(DF, TRUE, lapply(DF, NA2mean))
```

The last line could be replaced with the following if it's OK to overwrite the input:

```
DF[] <- lapply(DF, NA2mean)
```

Comment: Strange this doesn't have more upvotes or the best answer choice for that matter. Very succinct implementation. Thanks.

Comment: I added a 10% penalty for missing values, so my modification to this is: NA2mean <- function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), 1.1* mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))

Answer (score 21):

`dplyr`'s `mutate_all` or `mutate_at` could be useful here:

```
library(dplyr)                                                             

set.seed(10)                                                               
df <- data.frame(a = sample(c(NA, 1:3)    , replace = TRUE, 10),           
                 b = sample(c(NA, 101:103), replace = TRUE, 10),                            
                 c = sample(c(NA, 201:203), replace = TRUE, 10))                            

df         

#>     a   b   c
#> 1   2 102 203
#> 2   1 102 202
#> 3   1  NA 203
#> 4   2 102 201
#> 5  NA 101 201
#> 6  NA 101 202
#> 7   1  NA 203
#> 8   1 101  NA
#> 9   2 101 203
#> 10  1 103 201

df %>% mutate_all(~ifelse(is.na(.x), mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE), .x))          

#>        a       b        c
#> 1  2.000 102.000 203.0000
#> 2  1.000 102.000 202.0000
#> 3  1.000 101.625 203.0000
#> 4  2.000 102.000 201.0000
#> 5  1.375 101.000 201.0000
#> 6  1.375 101.000 202.0000
#> 7  1.000 101.625 203.0000
#> 8  1.000 101.000 202.1111
#> 9  2.000 101.000 203.0000
#> 10 1.000 103.000 201.0000

df %>% mutate_at(vars(a, b),~ifelse(is.na(.x), mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE), .x))

#>        a       b   c
#> 1  2.000 102.000 203
#> 2  1.000 102.000 202
#> 3  1.000 101.625 203
#> 4  2.000 102.000 201
#> 5  1.375 101.000 201
#> 6  1.375 101.000 202
#> 7  1.000 101.625 203
#> 8  1.000 101.000  NA
#> 9  2.000 101.000 203
#> 10 1.000 103.000 201
```

Comment: This is most usefull

Answer (score 20):

There is also quick solution using the **imputeTS** package:

```
library(imputeTS)
na_mean(yourDataFrame)
```

Comment: Honestly I think this is the best answer.  Knew there had to be some function in another package to do this common task.

Comment: ImputeTS gives good results in my opinion. There is another option included in this package and based on Kalman filters. ImputeTS developers also recommend it on their [info pages](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/imputeTS/vignettes/imputeTS-Time-Series-Missing-Value-Imputation-in-R.pdf). You can use it with the code.  `na_kalman(yourDataFrame)`

Answer (score 15):

To add to the alternatives, using @akrun's sample data, I would do the following:

```
d1[] <- lapply(d1, function(x) { 
  x[is.na(x)] <- mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  x
})
d1
```

Comment: @A Handcart And Mohair.  This is probably due to my limited background in programming:  what does including `x` in the third line do?

Comment: Running the code a bit, I'm inferring the point, here, is to return the whole vector `x`, rather than just the replacement values, and then overwrite the whole df `d1` (per the open brackets `[]`), rather than overwriting only the `NA`s.

Comment: @DanielFletcher, That's pretty much it.

Answer (score 11):

`lapply` can be used instead of a `for` loop.

```
d1[] <- lapply(d1, function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), mean(x, na.rm = TRUE), x))
```

This doesn't really have any advantages over the for loop, though maybe it's easier if you have non-numeric columns as well, in which case

```
d1[sapply(d1, is.numeric)] <- lapply(d1[sapply(d1, is.numeric)], function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), mean(x, na.rm = TRUE), x))
```

is almost as easy.

Comment: Interestingly, after lapply, my "gather" commands from dplyr don't work. :( I posted this on a different question.

Answer (score 9):

A one-liner using [tidyr's replace_na](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/replace_na.html) is

```
library(tidyr)
replace_na(mtcars,as.list(colMeans(mtcars,na.rm=T)))
```

If your `df` has columns that are non-numeric, this takes a little bit more work than a one-liner.

```
mean_to_fill <- select_if(ungroup(df), is.numeric) %>%
 colMeans(na.rm=T)

bind_cols(select(df, group1, group2, group3),
          select_if(ungroup(df), is.numeric) %>% 
            tidyr::replace_na(as.list(mean_to_fill))
          )
```

Answer (score 8):

You could also try:

```
 cM <- colMeans(d1, na.rm=TRUE)
 indx <- which(is.na(d1), arr.ind=TRUE)
 d1[indx] <- cM[indx[,2]]
 d1
```

#### data

```
set.seed(42)
d1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(NA,0:5), 5*10, replace=TRUE), ncol=10))
```

Answer (score 5):

Go simply with Zoo, it will simply replace all NA values with mean of the column values:

```
library(zoo)
na.aggregate(data)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
# Lets say I have a dataframe , df as following -
df <- data.frame(a=c(2,3,4,NA,5,NA),b=c(1,2,3,4,NA,NA))

# create a custom function
fillNAwithMean <- function(x){
    na_index <- which(is.na(x))        
    mean_x <- mean(x, na.rm=T)
    x[na_index] <- mean_x
    return(x)
}

(df <- apply(df,2,fillNAwithMean))
   a   b
2.0 1.0
3.0 2.0
4.0 3.0
3.5 4.0
5.0 2.5
3.5 2.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the answer pointed out by @Thomas,
This can also be done using `ifelse()` method of R:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(data)){
  data[,i]=ifelse(is.na(data[,i]),
                  ave(data[,i],FUN=function(y) mean(y, na.rm = TRUE)),
                  data[,i])
}
```

where, 
*Arguments* to `ifelse(TEST, YES , NO)` are:-

*TEST*- logical condition to be checked

*YES*- executed if the condition is True

*NO*- else when the condition is False

and `ave(x, ..., FUN = mean)` is method in R used for calculating averages of subsets of x[]

Answer (score 0):

With the data.table package you could use the `set()` function and loop over the columns and replace the `NA`s or whatever you like with an aggregate or value of your choice (*here:* mean):

```r
require(data.table)

# data
dt = copy(iris[ ,-5])
setDT(dt)
dt[1:4, Sepal.Length := NA] # introduce NAs

# replace NAs with mean (or whatever function you like)
for (j in seq_along(names(dt))) {
  set(dt,
      i = which(is.na(dt[[j]])),
      j = j, 
      value = mean(dt[[j]], na.rm = TRUE))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

R's `tidyr` package has a function just for this purpose: `replace_na`

```
meanvals <- as.list(colMeans(data, na.rm = TRUE))
data <- replace_na(data, meanvals)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Denis answer you can just use dplyr to calculate the means directly. If you add a prefix to the columns you would like to select, you can use either contains or ends/starts_with():

```
df <- df%>%
mutate_at(vars(starts_with("prefix_")), ####Select vars starting with "prefix_"
~replace_na(.x, mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE))) #### replace na with mean
```