# Error in 1:nrow(i) : argument of length 0 when using if...else in a second for loop

Tags: r

As a newbie I wanted to get better on loops and if...else statemets in R. I am trying to replace NAs using a for loops and if...else instead of  ifelse and lapply.However, I couldn't index the data properly in the if... else bit.

Example:

```
data<-data.frame(a<-c("a","b","c","d"),
                 b<-c("1","2",NA,"5"),
                 c<-c("10",NA,"30",40))

for (i in data){
  for (x in 1:nrow(i)){
    if (x==NA) {
      x<-mean(i,na.rm=T)
    }else
      x<-x
}
```

I get an error saying "Error in 1:nrow(i) : argument of length 0". Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

To address your error first: as you loop through the data frame, `i` is a 1D vector (i.e., a column of the data frame) and so `nrow` doesn't make any sense. To see this, try `for(i in data)print(nrow(i))`.

---

You're declaring individual vectors outside a data frame when you use the following syntax:

```
data<-data.frame(a<-c("a","b","c","d"),
                 b<-c("1","2",NA,"5"),
                 c<-c("10",NA,"30",40))
```

Just try typing `a` and you'll see it exists outside the data frame. Also, it means the data frame is defined incorrectly. Check it out:

```
  a....c..a....b....c....d.. b....c..1....2...NA...5..
1                          a                         1
2                          b                         2
3                          c                      <NA>
4                          d                         5
  c....c..10...NA...30...40.
1                         10
2                       <NA>
3                         30
4                         40
```

What you actually need is the following:

```
data <- data.frame(a = c("a","b","c","d"),
                   b = c("1","2",NA,"5"),
                   c = c("10",NA,"30",40))
```

which gives

```
  a    b    c
1 a    1   10
2 b    2 <NA>
3 c <NA>   30
4 d    5   40
```

Also, your braces for the loops don't match up correctly.

If you examine the class of each column in `data` by running `lapply(data, class)`, you'll see they're all `factor`s. Taking the mean – as you try to do in your code – is therefore meaningless. If columns `b` and `c` are meant to be numerics, then you don't need the quotation marks in their definition, like this:

```
data <- data.frame(a = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
                   b = c(1, 2, NA, 5),
                   c = c(10, NA, 30 ,40))
```

If column `a` was also a numeric, you could achieve your objective with this:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(data)){
  data[is.na(data[,i]), i] <- mean(data[,i], na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25835643/replace-missing-values-with-column-mean).

Comment: Thanks a lot, additional thanks for correcting my example !

Answer (score -1):

When checking for the existence of NAs you have to use the **is.na()** function, [since NAs work just as NULLs in relational databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)).

As an ilustration of how it works, you can run the following lines in your R console, and check the outputs:

```
1 == 1
1 == 2
1 == NA
NA == NA
is.na(NA)
```

This being said, if what you want is to replace NAs values in your data frame with column means, you can check [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25835643/replace-missing-values-with-column-mean).