# Dataset is baffling me

Tags: r

I'm trying to manipulate the following dataset (From FBI crime statistics) https://www.ucrdatatool.gov/Search/Crime/Local/RunCrimeJurisbyJuris.cfm . It is in .CSV format. Once downloaded, using R, I've used the following commands

```
a=read.csv("RunCrimeJurisbyJuris.csv",header=FALSE);
```

Then, we remove the stuff at the top, and the n/a at the end.

```
b=a[-c(1:5),-c(24,25)];
```

Which, when viewed, looks proper. For example, b[1,] produces the list of the first row, as it should However, when I try to name headers, for example,

```
 names(b)=b[1,],
```

Produces what *I THINK* is a list of the levels. Why is it doing this?

I get some very confusing stuff going on. I think this is due to when I look at, for example, b[1,1], instead of just getting "Year", I get

```
Year
41 Levels: ...
```

In addition, using view(b) produces an excel like representation that looks like a normal data set. It's been awhile since I've used R, and if I recall correctly, I've never seen this behavior before. In addition, I think these "Levels" are the source of the error. What am I doing wrong?

**ABOVE IS SOLVED**

Now, when I pull members, say, b["Population"], each element looks like this (number)" ". Is there a way to remove these " ", and if i pull a specific number, say b[3,2], it has the form "number". This dataset is quite frustrating (: .

Comment: Levels refers to a factor variable; it means that some variables have been read in as categorical factors, rather than numeric, variables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a factor to integer\numeric without loss of information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-integer-numeric-without-loss-of-information)

Comment: try to put `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in your `read.csv` command

Comment: @RLave This is intended, as the 24th/25th column are just a bunch of N/As when I imported it, and the first 5 rows are just unneeded information

Comment: @Mike Alright, I've never ran into this issue, even importing .csv-s with Strings in them. Very Interesting, I will report back momentarily

Comment: @Mike that worked, I was able to get the headers defined. Thanks!

Comment: It actually isn't entirely fixed, updating question at the moment.

Comment: @Shinaolord would you be able to share the dataset using dput instead of the link above

Comment: I will try to add it, I made it, not sure if I can upload files, but if not I'll use my github. My only issue now is removing NAs. I figured out how to as.numeric everything, should I just ask it in a new question? Your original suggestion did answer my original question, after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution involves the following::

First, to remove the "levels" part, we need to not make the strings as factors. Hence, we add the following command:

```
read.csv("file.csv",header=FALSE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Then, we have the issue of everything being strings, even the numbers( at least I did). I fixed this using the following loop, and `sapply()`

```
for(i in 1:ncol(test2)){test2[,i]=sapply(test2[,i],as.numeric)};
```

Using `as.numeric` to convert the strings to numbers. Then, we can replace the NA's by using a loop obtained from [Replacing Missing Values with Column Mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25835643/replace-missing-values-with-column-mean), which will only affect test on, say, statistical significance, or the production of confidence intervals. This is the loop stated in that quesiton, it's pretty easy to understand:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(test2)){ test2[is.na(test2[,i]),i]=mean(test2[,i],na.rm=TRUE)};
```

And, we're done!