# Selection of a column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'd like a write a loop in R which checks the the dataframe in order to change 0 values into a median. Unfortunately I get an error.

It's just a part of my loop.

```
y <- median(df[1])
Error in median.default(df[1]) : need numeric data
```

If I use, it works.

```
y <- median(df$name_of_the_column)
```

this is my loop. I haven't finished the loop. its still in process.

```
i = 1
for (x in df) {
  if (df[i][df[i] == 0]) {
    df[i][df[i]] <- median(df[i])
  }
```

Comment: Try `df[,1]` or `d[[1]]` as `df[1]` is still a data.frame with one column where as `[,1]` or `[[1]]` extracts the column as a vector as do `$` and `median` works on `vector` as input

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Its works. Now i have to work on my loop. This isn't working at all ;).

Comment: I posted a solution below with some explanations and a `for` loop

Comment: This may be relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25835643/replace-missing-values-with-column-mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on if you want 0s as part of your median calculation or not. Here are two tidyverse-based solutions, one that first converts the 0s to missing so they aren't part of the median calculation and another that includes them in the calculation (which is what it appears you have been doing):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

df<-
tibble(
  a=c(0:9),
  b=c(0:9),
  c=c(-2:7)
)
```

Converts 0s to NA then median:

```
df%>%
  mutate_all(
    list(~ifelse(.==0,NA,.))
  )%>%
  mutate_all(
    list(~ifelse(is.na(.),median(.,na.rm=TRUE),.))
  )
```

Converts 0s directly to median:

```
df%>%
  mutate_all(
    list(~ifelse(.==0,median(.,na.rm=TRUE),.))
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be easily done with `na.aggregate` after replacing the 0s with `NA`.  By default, the `na.aggregate` loops on each column and replace the `NA` with the `median` of that column

```
library(zoo)
na.aggregate(replace(df, df == 0, NA), FUN = median)
```

---

If we need a loop (here we are excluding the 0 while calculating the `median`)

```
for(i in seq_along(df)) {
  df[[i]] <-  replace(df[[i]], df[[i]] == 0, median(df[[i]][df[[i]] !=0]))
 }
```

---

Issue in the OP's post is based on applying the `median` on a `data.frame` as `median` expects input as `vector`.  According to `?median`

> x - an object for which a method has been defined, or a numeric vector containing the values whose median is to be computed.

We can either use `df[,1]` or `df[[1]]` to extract the column as a `vector` and then apply the `median` to get the same behavior as `$` (assuming that 'df' is `data.frame`)