# Replace missing value with mean of class within column

Tags: r, dplyr, multiple-columns, factors

I have a large dataset with some missing values (NAs). I'm looking to replace these values with the column means but **by class**, that is, where items in class k have a missing value in column j, that value will be replaced by the mean of values in column J *for items in class k.* Additionally, I want to do this with only base R or dplyr.

The class aspect brings an additional problem compared to the well-known one that's already been answered here: [Replace missing values with column mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25835643/replace-missing-values-with-column-mean).

In fact I can adapt one of the solutions there into a clumsy solution for my problem:

```
NA2mean <- function(x){replace(x, is.na(x), mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))}
DF %>% filter(DF$class=="A") -> A
A <- lapply(A,NA2mean)
```

(where the dataframe is DF and I have assumed the factor is stored in the column 'class'.)

Then you'd repeat this for every other class (e.g. B, C, D, E, F). Finally you could use DF <- rbind(A,B,C,D,E,F) to replace your old dataframe with the corrected one.

The dataframe in my case is ordered by class (i.e. A first, then B, then C, ...) and I'd like to keep it that way.

Any way of doing this much more efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, you could `group_by` `Class` and apply `NA2mean` for every column.

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>% group_by(class) %>% mutate_all(NA2mean)
```

In the newer version of `dplyr`, you can do this `across`

```
DF %>% group_by(class) %>% mutate(across(everything(), NA2mean))
```

Comment: Thanks! The simplest good solution, and you gave two of them.

Answer (score 1):

Base R Solution:

```
df[, sapply(df, is.numeric)] <-
  do.call("rbind", lapply(split(df[, sapply(df, is.numeric)], df$class), function(x) {
    x <- ifelse(is.na(x), mean(x, na.rm = TRUE), x)
  }))
```

Comment: Thank you! Nice solution

Answer (score 1):

We can use `na.aggregate` from `zoo`

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
DF %>%
  group_by(class) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-group_cols()), na.aggregate)
```

---

If we need `base R`

```
nm1 <- setdiff(names(DF), "class")
DF[nm1] <- lapply(DF[nm1], function(vec) ave(vec, class, FUN = NA2mean))
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I asked for base R and dplyr only.

Comment: @MobeusZoom `na.aggregate` automatically changes the NA by replacing with mean