# Replace the NA values of a column variable for the mean of each one

Tags: r, dataframe, mean, na

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAA6g.png

So I have the following data frame (df)  in which I have columns with some NA´s values. For the purpose of my project I really don't want to have any NA values. Moreover I need to replace all these NA values for the mean of each column variable.

Many Thanks

Comment: you may want to check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25835643/replace-missing-values-with-column-mean

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df %>%
  na.aggregate()
```

this will replace all NA values with the mean of each column

Comment: what exactly is not working? what is the error message ? did you install the librarys before running the code?

Comment: Actually there is no error, but when i make for example a str(df) to see some values of the variable, The NA´s are still there.

Comment: can you provide  an example of your data, e.g. with `dput()` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
NA2mean <- function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))
df<-replace(df, TRUE, lapply(df, NA2mean))
```

the answer