# Replacing NAs in a single vector of a dataframe

Tags: r

I'm trying to replace all of the NAs in a single column of a data frame with a calculated mean value.  I have different calculated means for each column, so I need to ensure I'm only replacing NAs in a single column.

Here is the code I'm using:

```r
df$column %>% replace_na(68.9)
```

I keep getting an error message saying I

> can't use $ for an atomic vector,
> but I don't think I am?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace missing values with column mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25835643/replace-missing-values-with-column-mean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are actually. The `tidyr::replace_na()` function works only on a data frame.

```r
df_with_replaced_na <- df %>% replace_na(list(column = 68.9))
# If you had more columns, it would be list(column1 = 67, column2 = 42) etc.
```

I understand that you want to impute your missing values with the mean of each column.

Here is a general solution

```r
library(tidyverse)
impute_na_with_mean <- function(x) dplyr::coalesce(x, mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))

impute_na_with_mean(c(1, 2, NA))
#> [1] 1.0 2.0 1.5

df %>% 
 mutate(across(where(anyNA) & where(is.numeric), .fns = impute_na_with_mean))
# That would change all your numeric columns with some NAs to this imputation method.
```

Answer (score 0):

`replace_na` works on a `data.frame` or `vector`.  According to `?replace_na`

> data - A data frame or vector.

-example

```
library(tidyr)
df <- data.frame(column = c(NA, 3, 2))
df$column %>% replace_na(68.9)
[1] 68.9  3.0  2.0
```

The issue maybe that the OP's data is not a data.frame, possibly a `matrix` or a `vector` where the `$` wouldn't work