# Replace Na's by the mean of the column using replace_na

Tags: r

This is my code:

```
data <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, NA, 4, 5),
                    y = c(6, 7, NA, 9, 10))

# Calcular a média de todas as colunas, incluindo NA's
mean <- colMeans(dados, na.rm = TRUE)

# Exibir o resultado
mean
```

Now replacing the Na's by the mean calulated above using replace_na function:

```
data %>% replace_na(list(mean))
```

I need to use the `replace_na()` function
Any help?

Comment: `list(mean)` creates a `list` with 1 element, the vector of means. Here you want `as.list(mean)`, which makes each element of `mean` a separate element of the list. Compare `list(1:3)` and `as.list(1:3)` to see the difference.

Comment: Thanks @GregorThomas  should I delete this question?

Comment: See this answer on the dupe-thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56317841/6461462

Comment: No, please don't delete! Duplicates are helpful pointers to where the answers are.

Answer (score 0):

replace_na() could work, but I would recommend sapply() instead:

```
data <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, NA, 4, 5),
                   y = c(6, 7, NA, 9, 10))

data[is.na(data)] <- sapply(data, function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))

print(data)
```